# Как инвертировать частотный спектр изображения?

Tags: изображения, преобразование, fft, фурье, обработка-сигналов

Возник вопрос: что будет, если перевернуть частотный спектр у сигнала – высокие частоты станут низкими, а низкие - высокими?

Не очень разбираюсь в математике обработки сигналов. В общих чертах представляю, что такое преобразование Фурье, и что такое частотное разложение изображения.

Для аудио сигнала, [как пишут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520557/how-to-spectrum-inverse-a-sampled-audio-signal), это делается тривиальным умножением на -1 сэмплов через один.

Интересно, как это сделать для двухмерного изображения? Как будет выглядеть картинка, в которой перевернули частотный спектр? И как это реализовать – намного ли сложнее, чем инверсия отсчётов через один?